# How to explore the bundles on the blocks builded by the external builders?

Tags: etherscan, mev, mev-boost

As far as I know, the flashbots bundles can be found in flashbots explorer (https://flashbots-explorer.marto.lol/) when their block is built by Flashbots: Builder (you can find more mev-builder at https://etherscan.io/accounts/label/mev-builder). However, the blocks build by other mev-builders, such as beaverbuild, builder0x69, and eth-builder, can not be found in flashbots explorer. How to find these bundles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On etherscan in the [block page](https://etherscan.io/block/16666425), there is the field "Fee Recipient" where is possible to identify the builder who propose the block.

[image]

It is not a complete information since one can not know the bundles, but is possible to supose some bundles inside the block, mainly because some interactions are to MEV contracts.

EDIT:
In [EigenPhi](https://eigenphi.io/) is possible to browse transactions that are part of MEV attacks.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that Flashbots: Builder is using Flashbots relay (you can find all mev-relays at https://ethstaker.cc/mev-relay-list/). However, it's not clear to me which relay is beaverbuild or builder0x69 using. Is there a many-to-many relationship between builer and relay?

Comment: @YuhuaWei Sorry, i forgot to tell you, but take a look at [EigenPhi](https://eigenphi.io/), in which you can find which transactions are MEV attacks. Accordingly to [https://www.relayscan.io/ list](https://www.relayscan.io/),  builder0x69 is using boost-relay.flashbots.net, relay.ultrasound.money, and some others.

Comment: Great! I have two questions. 1)  The data of the website (https://mevboost.pics/) shows that about 93.7 k blocks built by builder0x69 use flashbots as relay, while only about 6k blocks use ultra sound. What determines the connection of the same builder to different relays?  2) Different relays have their owning flitering, censorship and MEV strategies, as you can see at https://ethstaker.cc/mev-relay-list/. As an MEV researcher, how can one make sure that the builder who accepts his bundles will connect to the relay with the properties he desires, such as no filtering for frontrunning?

Comment: 1) Builders interact with relays using the [Relay API specification](https://flashbots.notion.site/Relay-API-Documentation-5fb0819366954962bc02e81cb33840f5), and is totally possible to interact with two or more relays, but i not aware if some relays demand the builder be whitelisted. 2) Beside to watch the builder activities using the links above i do not know other method to make sure that the builder will connect to the relay with the properties desired.